# ERROR [prerender-spa-plugin] - Unable to prerender all routes

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, url-routing

I have encountered a problem in implementing the prerender-spa-plugin with Laravel 5.7 and Vue 2.6:

```
Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/mnt/c/laragon/w  ww/<project-folder>/resources/views/index.html' in '/mnt/c/laragon/  www/<project-folder>':
  Error: Can't resolve '/mnt/c/laragon/www/<project-folder>/resources  /views/index.html' in '/mnt/c/laragon/www/<project-folder>'

  - compiler.js:79 childCompiler.runAsChild
    [<project-folder>]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16

  - Compiler.js:343 compile
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11

  - Compiler.js:671 hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:671:15


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [<project-folder>]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compiler.js:668 compilation.seal.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:668:31


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [<project-folder>]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1385 hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1385:35


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [<project-folder>]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1376 hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1376:32


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [<project-folder>]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1371 hooks.additionalAssets.callAsync.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1371:36


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [<project-folder>]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1367 hooks.optimizeTree.callAsync.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1367:32


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [<project-folder>]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1304 Compilation.seal
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1304:27

  - Compiler.js:665 compilation.finish.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:665:18

  - Compilation.js:1224 hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1224:4


  - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
    [<project-folder>]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

  - Compilation.js:1216 Compilation.finish
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1216:28

  - Compiler.js:662 hooks.make.callAsync.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:662:17


  - Compilation.js:1148 _addModuleChain
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1148:12

  - Compilation.js:1007 errorAndCallback.bail.err
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1007:6

  - Compilation.js:1038 moduleFactory.create
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1038:14

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:401 factory
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:130 resolver
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:224 asyncLib.parallel
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22

  - async.js:2830 
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/[neo-async]/async.js:2830:7

  - async.js:6877 
    [<project-folder>]/[webpack]/[neo-async]/async.js:6877:13
```

And I was following a blog tutorial on Vue and Laravel Implementation Section: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/01/vue-js-prerendering-node-laravel/

And set up my webpack.config.js (on the project root folder (copied content from laravel-mix webpack.config.js content + code from tutorial)):

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var PrerenderSPAPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')
var Renderer = PrerenderSPAPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer

/**
 * As our first step, we'll pull in the user's webpack.mix.js
 * file. Based on what the user requests in that file,
 * a generic config object will be constructed for us.
 */
let mix = require('./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/index');

let ComponentFactory = require('./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory');

new ComponentFactory().installAll();

require(Mix.paths.mix());

/**
 * Just in case the user needs to hook into this point
 * in the build process, we'll make an announcement.
 */

Mix.dispatch('init', Mix);

/**
 * Now that we know which build tasks are required by the
 * user, we can dynamically create a configuration object
 * for Webpack. And that's all there is to it. Simple!
 */

let WebpackConfig = require('./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig');

module.exports = new WebpackConfig().build();

module.exports.plugins.push(
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: Mix.paths.root('resources/views/index.html'),
    inject: false
  })
);

module.exports.plugins.push(
  new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
    staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    routes: [ '/' ]
  })
);
```

It generates index.html on ./public folder but the content is the error like from above.

Answer (score 0):

ok I fixed the problem by rendering less pages. It seems there is a problem with a poor connection, which in my case is not possible. So i figured that less pages to render will solve the problem and it did it for me.

I use vuejs with the VueCLI so i just commented out a few pages in the vue.config.js and voila, it worked.

Below you can find my vue.config.js

```
var PrerenderSpaPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') return

    return {
      plugins: [
        new PrerenderSpaPlugin(
           // Absolute path to compiled SPA
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
          // List of routes to prerender
          [ '/', 
            '/login',  
            '/whyRecruiters', 
            '/logoutinfo', 
            '/verifyemailinfo', 
            //'/deleteaccountinfo', 
          ],
        ),
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could your explain more please, because I have the same issue, I have only two pages as example, home and about.

Comment: Hi Zia, if you already have problems with only 2 pages, I can't help you much. In the beginning I tried to render more than 40 pages, then I commented out pages step by step in vue.config.js and in the end it worked 18 pages. I don't know why until today.

Comment: I was trying to prerender vue as a separate project from laravel, now I followed the link you shared, vue installed inside laravel.  
Could you share your weback.config.js, I followed the same tutorial you said, in Laravel 7 and Vue2, `push is undefined` here `module.exports.plugins.push(`

Comment: Hey Zia, sure. I added my vue.config.js (I don't have a webpack.config.js). I deleted most of the pages in the list but I guess you get the idea. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
headless: true
```

Reference:
https://juejin.cn/post/6844904178326700045#comment

Comment: Please add a bit more explanation to your answer

Comment: It's already headless by default